# questions about Folland real analysis chapter 1 exercise

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

[image]

Here, E is a Lesbegue-measurable set on the real line. This is the exercise 30, 31 of p. 40 of Folland real analysis. I solved these problems when E is of finite measure, but the problem requires that E may be of infinite measure. I'm quite desperate about how to solve these for general cases. Could anyone show me how to prove them?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}(n,n+1]$. Since $m(E)>0$, it must be the case that $m(E\cap(n,n+1])>0$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z$. But $m(E\cap(n,n+1])\leq m((n,n+1])=1$, so the problem may be effectively reduced to the case in which $m(E)<\infty$, which you claim to have already proved.

Comment: This is essentially a well known result known as [Steinhaus lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

this will be the desired solution for problem 30.

Comment: write the answer in a compact form using MathJax

Comment: I am sry brother but I don't know how to use it and how to write in it, that's why I wrote on a piece of paper and attached the picture of the proof

Comment: see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more details and use it next time.